# Critique of enum

Tags: java, enum

I'm working my way through *The Java Programming Language, Fourth Edition - The Java Series*.  This is Exercise 6.4:

> Expand your traffic light color enum from Exercise 6.1 on page 152 so that each enum constant has a suitable Color object that can be retrieved with getColor.

The enum from Exercise 6.1 is as follows:

```
enum TrafficLightColor {
    GREEN,
    RED,
    YELLOW,
}
```

Is the following an adequate solution?

```
enum TrafficLightColor {
    GREEN(0, 255, 0),
    YELLOW(255, 255, 0),
    RED(255, 0, 0);

    Color color;

    TrafficLightColor (int r, int g, int b) {
        color = new Color(r, g, b);
    }

    Color getColor() {
        return color;
    }
}

public class Color {
    private int r;
    private int g;
    private int b;

    Color(int r, int g, int b) {
        this.r = r;
        this.g = g;
        this.b = b;
    }

    public int getR() {
        return r;
    }

    public int getG() {
        return g;
    }

    public int getB() {
        return b;
    }
}

public class TrafficLight {
    private TrafficLightColor currentColor;

    TrafficLight(TrafficLightColor currentColor) {
        this.currentColor = currentColor;
    }

    TrafficLightColor getCurrentColor() {
        return currentColor;
    }
}

import org.junit.Test;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

public class TrafficLightTest {
    @Test
    public void testGetCurrentColor() throws Exception {
        TrafficLight light = new TrafficLight(TrafficLightColor.GREEN);
        assertEquals(0, light.getCurrentColor().getColor().getR());
        assertEquals(255, light.getCurrentColor().getColor().getG());
        assertEquals(0, light.getCurrentColor().getColor().getB());

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Certainly, that seems adequate.  You may want to make the `color` field `private`, though.  Otherwise having a getter is pretty irrelevant.  Also, I would make the field `final` so that the associated color can never be modified.

Were you told to code your own `Color` class?  There's [already one provided for you](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html) in `java.awt`.

Comment: Good catch Jeff. I've updated the color field to be:
private final Color color; Is it good form to update the original post with the correction, or leave as is? The exercise was vague on which Color class to use, but I will have a look at java.awt. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: @weare138 I think you're supposed to leave it as is?  But who knows.  And no problem!